# where can I find ros cheat cheet

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find ros cheat cheet ,where can I find it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199003/where-can-i-find-ros-cheat-cheet/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the  post on the ROS News page, you can find it at the [clearpathrobotics.com/Technical Documentation - ROS Education](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/resources/technical-documentation/) (scroll down to the bottom).

That is for Hydro, but I don't think too much has changed in Indigo (or at least not the bits that are on the cheat sheet).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The official source is here: https://github.com/ros/cheatsheet

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1